# Java for GPS gets lots of errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, location

I'm trying to make a link to GPS but it's all got many errors

The Code:

```
package com.f.fa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.google.android.maps.Activity;

public class PageFour extends Activity {

    Button nwloc;

    @Override
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapslocations);

        MapView view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.nwloc);
        view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        MapController control = view.getControler();

        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListner listener = new LocationListner() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        control.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude(), (int)location.getLongitude()));
    }
        };
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listner);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;

    }
}
```

Here is as it looks like + the Emulator control" is not highlighted
http://oi59.tinypic.com/2r7rnnl.jpg

I didn't choose "Google API" at the beginning.

Help :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the Google Play Services in your project

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html